# Create link to the top of a page which contains a certain labelled object

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdftex

I want to create a clickable link from which I can jump to the top of the page which contains a certain labelled object. I tried `\pageref` but then clicking on the corresponding link results in a jump to the *exact site* of the labelled object [formula `(1)` in the MWE below]. Instead, I want to jump to the top of the corresponding page [top of page 2 in the MWE below]. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{equation}\label{a}
  a:=b
\end{equation}
\lipsum
Note that $a$ is defined in (\ref{a}) on page \pageref{a}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one approach if `hyperref` option `hypertexnames` is set (it is by default):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand{\pagereftop}[1]{\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\pageref*{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{equation}\label{a}
  a:=b
\end{equation}
\lipsum
Note that $a$ is defined in (\ref{a}) on page \pagereftop{a}.
\end{document}
```